# Calling a Helperfunction inside a select statement, persisting the returned results for multiple values

Tags: c#

I am building a JSON string and in the rows section, I have two values that I want to build and pass in the JSON string which are calculated by a helper function. I am wondering if there a way to call this helper function once, and return back an array of values (two in my case) so I don't have to call the helper function twice (and avoid hitting the database twice).

Example Code

```
            rows = (
                from tempItem in pagedQuery.ToList()
                select new
                {
                    cell = new string[] {                    
                        tempItem.Name,
                        tempItem.Regular,
                        HelperFunction.GetPrice(tempItem.ID, false).ToString(),
                        tempItem.Premium,
                        HelperFunction.GetPrice(tempItem.ID, true).ToString(),
                    }
                }).ToArray()
```

Example Function:

```
public decimal GetPrice(int ID, bool Premium)
{
  Item item = databaseCallToGetPrice(ID).first();

  if (Premium)
      return item.ExamplePrice;
  else
      return item.PremiumExamplePrice;
}
```

So what I am asking is in my example I call the Helper function twice, is there a way to call on it just the once and then return back an array that I can somehow persist and then use twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a `Tuple<decimal, decimal>` from the function:

```
public Tuple<decimal, decimal> GetPrices(int ID)
{
    Item item = databaseCallToGetPrice(ID).First();
    return Tuple.Create(item.ExamplePrice, item.PremiumExamplePrice);
}
```

Then use that:

```
rows = (
        from tempItem in pagedQuery.ToList()
        let prices = HelpererFunction.GetPrices(tempItem.ID)
        select new
        {
            cell = new string[] {                    
                tempItem.Name,
                tempItem.Regular,
                prices.Item1.ToString(),
                tempItem.Premium,
                prices.Item2.ToString(),
            }
        }).ToArray()
```

IMHO a tuple is better than a simple array because you're guaranteed to get two and only two items back from the function.

---

If you want to be even clearer, you can create a struct

```
public struct Prices
{
    public decimal PremiumPrice, Price;       

    public Prices(decimal premium, decimal price)
    {
        PremiumPrice = premium;
        Price = price;
    } 
}
```

then return that from the helper function

```
public Prices GetPrices(int ID)
{
    Item item = databaseCallToGetPrice(ID).First();
    return new Prices(item.PremiumExamplePrice, item.ExamplePrice);
}
```

and use that:

```
rows = (
        from tempItem in pagedQuery.ToList()
        let prices = HelpererFunction.GetPrices(tempItem.ID)
        select new
        {
            cell = new string[] {                    
                tempItem.Name,
                tempItem.Regular,
                prices.Price.ToString(),
                tempItem.Premium,
                prices.PremiumPrice.ToString(),
            }
        }).ToArray()
```

Comment: This is a very impressive answer and as far as I can see completely answers my question. Bravo, and chalk up another win for the Stack Overflow Community!  I'm implementing this immediately!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Let` AFAIK

```
rows = (
                from tempItem in pagedQuery.ToList()
                let prices = HelpererFunction.GetPrice(tempItem.ID)
                select new
                {
                    cell = new string[] {                    
                        tempItem.Name,
                        tempItem.Regular,
                        prices[0].ToString() ,
                        tempItem.Premium,
                        prices[1].ToString() ,
                    }
                }).ToArray()
```

You can refactor your GetPrice function to return an decimal[]

```
public decimal[] GetPrice(int ID)
{
  Item item = databaseCallToGetPrice(ID).first();

  return new [] {item.ExamplePrice, item.PremiumExamplePrice};
}
```

Comment: LOL wow, you got in before my edit... would this work for price as an array and then feeding price[0], and price[1]?

Comment: This wouldn't work as the OP is calling `GetPrice(n, false)` once and `GetPrice(n, true)` the second time

Comment: @lc, that is true, but he wants to return an array from GetPrice, and get rid of the boolean flag, if I am understanding him correctly.

Comment: Yes, I wish to remove the boolean and only have to hit the DB the once returning the value for the "regular" and the "premium"